# Why R says it is not NA, while it is NA?

Tags: r, na

I have vector called **stuff**

```
[1] "Apple"     "Banana"      "Coco" "Cucumber"   "Donut"    "Egg"     "Granate"    
 [8] "Lemon"    "Orange"  "Pineapple"    "Potato" "Quinoa"     "Tea"  "Tangerine"    
[15] "Tuna"  "Wax"   "Yuzu"    "Zuccini"       ""
```

If I ask `is.na(stuff)` it gives me

```
> is.na(stuff)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

but apparently the last one is `NA`. What is wrong?

Comment: last one is not NA, it is empty string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last one isn't NA, it's an empty string, which are different. NA means that you don't have a value in that position of the vector. The empty string is telling you that you do have a value, and its value is a string with 0 characters.